# Dynamic CRM 2015 On-Premises Audit History aligning UI issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We have problems with Dynamics CRM 2015 On-Premises audit history.

Fields are misaligned, as you can see on attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBV45.png). 
Possibly, this UI issue appears, due to pictures (icons) size (picture is a bit larger then plain text).

Did someone face with same UI issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is known product issue since CRM 2011 rollup 12. Due to those icons in the right hand side.

FYR: https://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/author/crmconsultant1/page/2/

Refer 68th point.

kindly correct me if I'm wrong :)